# box-sizing: border-box a bit quirky in safari?

Tags: css, safari

This code:

```
<div class="green">
    <div class="red" style="height: 25%"></div> * 4
</div>

.red {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

...looks fine in IE8, Chrome 24 and Firefox 18:

[image]

But in Safari  (5.1.7) I get some extra unwanted bottom margin/transparent border:

[image]

Full test code on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ozefar/6/edit

Am I missing something in my css?